# How to build NixOS/nixpkgs manuals?

Tags: nix, nixos

How to build manuals for NixOS and nixpkgs?

I also get an error sometimes:

```
error: a 'aarch64-linux' with features {} is required to build '...options.xml.drv', but I am a 'x86_64-linux' with features {benchmark, big-parallel, kvm, nixos-test}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For NixOS:

```sh
$ nix-build nixos/release.nix -A manualHTML.x86_64-linux
```

For Nixpkgs:

```sh
$ nix-build doc
```

When building NixOS manual you get an error

```
error: a 'aarch64-linux' with features {} is required to build '...options.xml.drv', but I am a 'x86_64-linux' with features {benchmark, big-parallel, kvm, nixos-test}
```

it means you forgot to specify `.x86_64-linux` attribute.